# How to not let the gap between two div vary when text to one of the div is added?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have placed two divs in a `flex-direction row` with a `gap of 70px` as shown in the figure:

[image]

In the above picture, we could see the date to be 8/12/22 but when we change the date to 12/12/22 the gap between the divs(i.e date and step counts) slightly increases due to the extra digit added to the date. This gives a very bad user experience.

Here is the code:

#### JS

```html
<div className="DataAreaParent">
  <div className="DataParent">
    <span id="XAxisData" className="SpanText"></span>
    <b className="BoldText">{props.xAxis} </b>
  </div>
  <div className="DataParent">
    <span id="YAxisData" className="SpanText"></span>
    <b className="BoldText">{props.yAxis}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
.DataAreaParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 70px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.DataParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.BoldText {
  color: gray;
}

.SpanText {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Please guide me on how the gap will not change even though digits in the date increase or decrease.

Comment: i guess you should use a fixed width for the left span

Comment: @Apostolos fixing the width worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
.DataAreaParent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    # You can this line to set the auto gap between flexed container.
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shachar297 but your answer is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the fixed gap and the width is not assigned to `.DataAreaParent`.

Remove the fixed gap and add the width in `.DataAreaParent` like,

```
.DataAreaParent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* gap: 70px; */
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}
```

Also, add min-width to date and align it to the left of its container. It will solve your problem.

```
.DataParent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 58px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add fixed width to `XAxisData` and `YAxisData`

```
#XAxisData {
  width: 85px;
}

#YAxisData {
  width: 50px;
}
```

You also add `align-items: flex-end;` to `DataParent` class to avoid distraction in box e.g.

```
.DataParent {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```